# Is there any time limit for accepting an answer from the community?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

This is related to my own question and answer on Stack Overflow, "[Detect autoscroll position value change in panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768576/detect-autoscrollposition-value-change-in-panel)".

If a user answers his/her own question then what is the time limit for accepting that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Robert I didn't get you. How can i accept answer in case  it is my own question and i had replied for the same.

Comment: @mahesh You should already be able to; that question was asked 70 hours ago

Comment: @Mahesh, it's not the community that's going to accept any answer. It's always the question asker who decides on that. (And if the question asker and question answerer are the same person, then there's the 48 hour waiting period.)

Comment: @Arjan, let me know if the question asker and answer is same and if his answer is wrong and he accepted his answer as per time limit of community than?

Comment: @mahesh: Sorry, I don't understand the time limit part, but if the accepted answer is by the questioner himself (or herself), it will *not* be put at the top of the answers unlike the usual case. Therefore, when viewing answers sorted by votes, the answer with the most upvotes will be displayed, and the self-accepted answer can be down-voted to oblivion if it is actually not helpful at all. That is the way the community deals with incorrect answers, but the "accepted" checkmark can *only* be set by the question's OP.

Comment: @mahesh, just to be sure: when talking about "the community" I mean "the users". So: not some automatic system. If the accepted answer is wrong, then "the community" might give some better answer more upvotes, or maybe even given the wrong answer downvotes, or post some comments below the wrong answer, or maybe even edit the wrong answer to fix it...