# Why Not Provide Points On Own Question’s Answer

Tags: discussion

I have personally feel that there should be change in points system against own question’s answer. My base on **SO question and answer.**  There is system to provide points on peer’s answer it’s good. I agree with as their answer is valuable and useful to others. So my question is  the answer provide by questioner is not valuable or is not useful to others?. If so than there is no need to submit answer on own’s question.
As per my point of view questioner’s answer is as important as others peers answer. The points is the medium to encourage peers as well as questioners and I think it’s the main base of our community. So Why not it’s leave up to mediator to provide points on own question’s  answer by rectifying correct or incorrect?.  It should be encourages both.
I wants to being understand well about it.

## Bottam Line Question is :

**Questioners' answer to his own question is useful or not?**

Comment: Eh? Are you talking about accepting your own answer or voting for your own answer, or what?

Comment: If you're so worried about reputation points: [7 out of your 40 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A439582+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3A0) *do* have answers, but you did not accept any. And you only upvoted other people 6 times. That's less than 1 vote per month. Wow.

Comment: @Arjan, You told me that you have not expertise on area of c# than How do you come to know that 7 out of my 40 question is correct?.

Comment: You don't only have to vote on your own questions! (I am leaving this discussion now.)

Comment: No the __Bottom Line Question is__ not if answering your own questions is useful (it is) but if it is something that should be done to contribute something back to the community and if rewarding that behavior allows for the system to be gamed. Of course neither of those are interesting questions because the answer to both of them is a resounding, overwhelming __yes__! Thank you, please come again.

Comment: @aaronasterling, That means we should stop to submit answer to our own questions right?

Comment: ... I think system allow to answer to questioners' own question it is useless. what is base behind to allow like this?

Comment: @mahesh, no it means that you __should__ answer your own questions __if__ you have a good answer. You should __not__ expect to get any rep for doing so.

Comment: @aaronasterling, but if you nothing to earn from your works than it is meaningless of that works?. it is genuine reason that people should avoid it due to lac of earnings.

Comment: @mahesh 17 points is nothing. I really wouldn't worry about it. I'd worry about helping other people. If somebody doesn't want to provide an answer but is willing to for 17 points, then I'm probably not interested in seeing their answer to begin with.

Comment: @aaronasterling, Now you are my type guy. I appreciate your comment. See I also believe in helping to new comer it is my main base. you can see my each question answer are for only new comer as well as for community also.

Comment: ...But i personally feel that there is something wrong with system. As one part community allow to submit answer on own question

Comment: ... and other part community give importance to peers question only. not on questioners' answer.

Comment: ...this partiality are killing me. to help others.

Answer (score 6):

That is likely by design to prevent gaming of the system. You should still provide a good answer because once others see it and find it useful they will vote your answer up and you'll gain reputation points for your effort that way.

Comment: I think that game is very very important who provide us knowledge.and the knowledge is important not game.

Comment: ... and i am not against to provide better answer by others. but if there is no answer by other than.

Comment: @mahesh, *gaming* means *abusing* here. Even the time to *undo* votes was reduced because some people [found ways to abuse that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046).

Answer (score 4):

Other people can upvote the answer of the person who asked the question and he will get 10 reputation points for each upvote.

I am concerned that giving the 15 rep for *accepting* an answer from the same person who asked the question would be a motivation to just post a summary. So the people who provided the real answer are not rewarded.

Comment: @nhnb, If there is no answer provide by some one except questioner's answer against particulars question asked than?.

Comment: @mahesh, so you want to get points for accepting *your own* answer? But then surely people (not you!) would start asking bad questions, and post bad answers to their own bad questions. They would then earn 15 points by accepting their own answer.

Comment: @Arjan, Now you decide here is my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232616/add-row-to-bound-dgv-by-textbox/4233375#4233375.  Is it bad? or is there anything wrong moto or is there anthing abusing?

Comment: ... and arjan in my above question I have mention about to decide it by mediator whether such thing wrong or right?

Comment: @mahesh, C# is not my area of expertise, so I don't know if [your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232616/add-row-to-bound-dgv-by-textbox/4233375#4233375) is the best. But: if you solved your own question, then after waiting 48 hours you can accept your own answer. (But [you already knew that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65642/84237)) You just won't get the 15 points for that. Who cares? You've asked 40 questions and answered 9, so apparently Stack Overflow works well for you?

Comment: @Arjan, yes you are right but the question is not here about who is the best?. the question is about the encouragement. If there is no answer of their own question they worked hard on it. and publish here for knowledge.

Comment: ... Is their efforts is useless or not important? or their answer is not for useful to others?

Comment: ... if so then it would ultimately discouragement.The people who try to solve their own would not publish here after they found the solution.

Comment: @mahesh, encourage *others* please! A quick count: you got about 70 answers for your 40 questions. You only upvoted 6 of those, but still want reputation for answering your own question. Why? Also, like @nhnb answered: earning points that way will make *some* people abuse that. Having "mediators" accept the answers to avoid that, is just a waste of time.

Comment: @Arjan, You are 100% right the perfect voting system is comes to know to me is when i started to solve the others' question. and i think it's about one or half month before I started it. now i know how to voted to others. and the value of votes.

Comment: ... and remember there is no down voted in my accounts which i down voted others. I simply believe it's discourage the people and misguided. instead of down voted show to them their mistake it's my moto